# MonoMac TableView not calling GetObjectData

Tags: nstableview, monomac

I'm struggling to get the NSTableView working in MonoMac (as a replacement for System.Windows.Forms.ListView), and I'm very puzzled about why my GetObjectData method isn't being called.  I've put in debug prints, and the "GetRowCount" method in my NSTableViewSource is being called properly, but it never makes it to GetObjectData.  I get a table with the right number of rows, even selection works, but there's no data in the rows.  ReloadData also works, in that there's another call to GetRowCount.

Here's the code:

```
public class MyTableViewSource : NSTableViewSource
{
    //... (constructor, etc.)

    public override int GetRowCount(NSTableView table)
    {
        Debug.Print ("NumberOfRowsInTableView = {0}", mSFList.RowCount);
        return mSFList.RowCount;
    }

    // TODO: Why is this not being called!!!
    public override NSObject GetObjectValue(NSTableView table, NSTableColumn col, int row)
    {
        Debug.Print ("Getting data for row {0}, column titled {1}", row, col.HeaderCell.Title);
        // Get the column index.
        int colIndex;
        NSTableColumn[] cols = table.TableColumns();
        for (colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols.Length; colIndex++)
            if (cols[colIndex] == col) break;
        if (colIndex >= cols.Length) return null;
        return new NSString(mSFList[row,colIndex]);
    }
```

I even tried forcing things with this Export, but I don't know if I have the string right.

```
    [Export("tableView:getObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:")]
    public NSObject MyGetObjectValue(NSTableView table, NSTableColumn col, int row)
    {
        return GetObjectValue(table, col, row);
    }
```

The Debug output is always very consistent:

```
NumberOfRowsInTableView = 2
```

Any ideas?  I wonder if I did everything right on the XCode side, but I didn't mess with the table, I don't see how I could have blocked this method.

Xamarin Studio 5.5, but I'm keeping Mono at version 3.8.0 for now (3.10 has issues with some Windows code I use).

Comment: (And yes, I do have multiple columns - 3 - and I also get a response when I click on one of the column headers, "DidClickTableColumn" is called.)

Comment: Did you ever work this out, I'm stuck with the same issue

Comment: I actually gave up on TableView completely.  My purpose was to approximately replicate the ListView from Windows Forms, and I was able to do this quite easily by creating my own custom class derived from NSView.  I had to draw my own table lines and populate it with text, but there's nothing really hard about that, and the XCode interface builder makes it easy to seat a custom view inside a ScrollView.  I wound up doing that for some of my other UI as well; it seems like a better fit than trying to shoehorn my desired UI paradigms into Mac UI elements.

Comment: I just ran into this issue, and GetObjectValue is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from my comment above, I retried the whole setup, deleted old tables and inserted new ones and it now works. Though I am using ObjectValueForTableColumn rather than getObjectValue.

I used the steps provided @ the following [link](http://www.netneurotic.de/Mono/MonoMac-NSTableView.html) (Credits: Andrew J. Brehm)

Comment: I am unable to verify this approach because I'm no longer using NSTableView, but it's very plausible and working for you, so I'm accepting it as the answer.